# List the name (or names) of the employee in department 30 who make the highest salary in that department

Tags: sql

List the name (or names) of the employee in department 30 who make the highest salary in that department

```
SQL> SELECT DEPTNO, ENAME, SAL
     FROM EMP
     WHERE SAL IN (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP)
     AND EMP.DEPTNO = 30;
```

no rows selected

SUPPOSE TO LOOK LIKE:

```
    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
        30 BLAKE             2850
```

Comment: Please add your table schemas to your question, and if possible, sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DEPTNO, ENAME, SAL
FROM EMP
WHERE SAL IN (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP) AND
      EMP.DEPTNO = 30
```

Your query is selecting all employees in department 30 who earn the highest overall salary.

You need the condition both in the inner query and the outer query:

```
SELECT e.DEPTNO, e.ENAME, e.SAL
FROM EMP e
WHERE e.SAL = (SELECT MAX(e2.SAL)
               FROM EMP e2
               WHERE e2.DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO
              ) AND
      e.DEPTNO = 30;
```

The subquery is called a *correlated subquery* because the `WHERE` condition is linked to the outer query.